# Get elements by tag name VBA

Tags: html, vba

I'm trying to get the value `this_is_the_text_i_need_to_get` out the following HTML source code:

```
<div class="blubrBoxContent">
     <input id="url" type="text" name="__url" 
             value="this_is_the_text_i_need_to_get">
</div>
```

This is the VBA code that I've got so far:

```
Set TDelements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("div")

For Each TDelement In TDelements
    If TDelement.ID = "url" Then
         MyVar = TDelement.innerText("Value")
    End if
Next
```

The thing is that I can't make the code to go into the `If` statement. It looks like `ID` is not a property of the `TDelement`.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("input")` - you're not looking for a `div` with that id but an `input`. And it would just be `TDelement.value`

Comment: I changed and doesn't get the value that i need. the fact that the "input" is inside of div tag could affect the result?

Comment: Within your loop add `Debug.Print TDelement.ID, TDelement.Value` - do you get the output you'd expect?

Comment: Thank you Tim ! that's how i have it, but looks like input is not a TagName since is inside of <div class="blubrBoxContent"> because i'm not getting what i'm expecting.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` doesn't care where the tag is: if you call it on the document then it will find all instances of that tag whether or not they're nested in other elements.  Maybe you can share a bit more of the relavant code.

Comment: <div class="bluBrdrBox1">
<div class="blubr1ct"></div>
<div class="blubrBoxContent">
<input id="url" type="text" name="__url" value="http://bit.ly/1dJ17Yg">
</div>

Comment: I know the last comment is  not in the best format,  but as you can see in the top the input doesn't have the closing tag </input> as the others tags. that's why i guess this is not a tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your HTML (at least, there's no problem because most browsers can deal with mal-formed HTML pretty well since there's so much of it out there)

Add a reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim doc As New HTMLDocument, els, el

    doc.body.innerHTML = "<div class='bluBrdrBox1'> <div class='blubr1ct'></div>" & _
                    "<div class='blubrBoxContent'><input id='url' type='text' " & _
                    "name='__url' value='bit.ly/1dJ17Yg'></div>"
                    ;
    Set els = doc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each el In els
        Debug.Print el.ID, el.Value
    Next el

End Sub
```

Comment: it works with that piece of HTML but when i try to read it from the whole webpage it don't come up. Please try to go to this link "http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/digital-media/9781605669182/reflections-and-proposals-on-public-officials-training-and-promotion-of-e-government1/ch019_s1_002?cid=shareLink&reader=html&imagepage=" on the upper right side of the corner there is a "Share" button click there and a new window will pop up if you inspect that link in the HTML you will see the piece of information that i'm trying to get, this "http://bit.ly/1bZe7N1 .   from that link wont come up.

Comment: I figured out that the link that i'm looking for wont be available in the HTML unless you click on that share button and the pop up window comes up. I Guess the way to go is invoke the click method, then look for that.

Comment: That is on piece of code I was looking for last 6 hours.